# uap:VisualElements BackgroundColor not working correctly

Tags: windows, uwp, desktop-bridge

When using the Project Centennial app bridge, I would like to be able to have the icon as it appears on the taskbar be without a colored border.

This gives a grey border

```
<uap:VisualElements
DisplayName="productname"
Description="productdescription"
BackgroundColor="gray"
Square150x150Logo="Assets\appicon.150x150.png"
Square44x44Logo="Assets\appicon.44x44.png"
/>
```

As does this

```
<uap:VisualElements
DisplayName="productname"
Description="productdescription"
BackgroundColor="#777777"
Square150x150Logo="Assets\appicon.150x150.png"
Square44x44Logo="Assets\appicon.44x44.png"
/>
```

But this gives a bright blue border

```
<uap:VisualElements
DisplayName="productname"
Description="productdescription"
BackgroundColor="transparent"
Square150x150Logo="Assets\appicon.150x150.png"
Square44x44Logo="Assets\appicon.44x44.png"
/>
```

This is the official list of supported colors for the BackgroundColor field according to [Microsoft's Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap-visualelements).

aliceBlue, antiqueWhite, aqua, aquamarine, azure, beige, bisque, black, blanchedAlmond, blue, blueViolet, brown, burlyWood, cadetBlue, chartreuse, chocolate, coral, cornflowerBlue, cornsilk, crimson, cyan, darkBlue, darkCyan, darkGoldenrod, darkGray, darkGreen, darkKhaki, darkMagenta, darkOliveGreen, darkOrange, darkOrchid, darkRed, darkSalmon, darkSeaGreen, darkSlateBlue, darkSlateGray, darkTurquoise, darkViolet, deepPink, deepSkyBlue, dimGray, dodgerBlue, firebrick, floralWhite, forestGreen, fuchsia, gainsboro, ghostWhite, gold, goldenrod, gray, green, greenYellow, honeydew, hotPink, indianRed, indigo, ivory, khaki, lavender, lavenderBlush, lawnGreen, lemonChiffon, lightBlue, lightCoral, lightCyan, lightGoldenrodYellow, lightGreen, lightGray, lightPink, lightSalmon, lightSeaGreen, lightSkyBlue, lightSlateGray, lightSteelBlue, lightYellow, lime, limeGreen, linen, magenta, maroon, mediumAquamarine, mediumBlue, mediumOrchid, mediumPurple, mediumSeaGreen, mediumSlateBlue, mediumSpringGreen, mediumTurquoise, mediumVioletRed, midnightBlue, mintCream, mistyRose, moccasin, navajoWhite, navy, oldLace, olive, oliveDrab, orange, orangeRed, orchid, paleGoldenrod, paleGreen, paleTurquoise, paleVioletRed, papayaWhip, peachPuff, peru, pink, plum, powderBlue, purple, red, rosyBrown, royalBlue, saddleBrown, salmon, sandyBrown, seaGreen, seaShell, sienna, silver, skyBlue, slateBlue, slateGray, snow, springGreen, steelBlue, tan, teal, thistle, tomato, **transparent**, turquoise, violet, wheat, white, whiteSmoke, yellow, yellowGreen

They all work except "transparent".  Hexadecimal #RRGGBB values work correctly.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Or is this just yet another case of M$ having incorrect documentation?

Comment: Same issue here. It works for UWP apps but not converted app.

Comment: Can you clarify (by posting an image) what is the actual vs expected result? The tiles/icons should work the same way for UWP and converted apps. I recommend using the visual asset generator in VS2017 to generate them correctly for packaging. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to add unplated assets.

You will need to run makepri on your assets.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-manual-conversion#optional-add-target-based-unplated-assets